# How can I vectorize or optimize a function to reduce the time taken in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to calculate matching score of two arrays, each array size is bit higher. I know we can use numpy to vectorize certain calculation but when it comes to strings inside array I heard there's no way to vectorize them. So I wrote a function like this,

This is very sample data, my array size is bit higher than this example,

```
data1 = [["a", "b", "c"], ["c", "d", "A", "f"], ["a", "z", "k", "p"]]
data2 = {"a": ["A", "aa", "a"], "b": ["B", "bb"], "c": ["C", "cc"]}

def calculate_match_score(data1, data2) -> dict:

    matched_: int = 0
    for x, y in data2.items():
        for z in data1:

            if x.lower() == z.lower() or any(
                z.lower() == var.lower() for var in y
            ):
                matched_ += 1
                break  # exit out once matched

    score = (matched_ / len(data2)) * 100.0

    return {"score": score}

for d in data1:
    print(calculate_match_score(d, data2))
```

This is taking around 15 - 23 seconds for 10000 inner lists in data1 through sequentially via for loop on my original data.

Note: Inside the function I thought of using multithreading, but due to GIL it won't actually be multiple tasks at once. So I wrote a basic for loop.

Is there any way to get this under a second or two using something in python? Latency is very important in my use-case

Comment: I'd lower everything before actual processing: `data1_l= [[j.lower() for j in i] for i in data1]`, `data2_l = {k: [i.lower() for i in v] for k, v in data2.items()}`. Then your function could be replaced with: `sum(k == i or i in v for k, v in data2_l.items() for i in d) / len(d) * 100.0`

Answer (score 1):

So here is my tweaked version of your code:

```
%%timeit

data1 = [["a", "b", "c"], ["c", "d", "A", "f"], ["a", "z", "k", "p"]]
data2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
length = len(data2)
data2 = set(data2 + [x*2 for x in data2])

def calculate_match_score(data1, data2, length) -> dict:
    matched_: int = 0
    for x in data1:
        if x.lower() in data2:
            matched_ += 1
    score = (matched_ / length) * 100.0
    return {"score": score}

for _ in range(1000000):
    for d in data1:
        res = calculate_match_score(d, data2, length)
```

This ran 1 million loops on my machine with result:

```
2.33 s ± 78.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Converting data2 to `set()` gives benefit due to checking by hashing, but making the set also takes some time, so the benefit is less than 100ms over 100k iterations, so a list can be used directly instead of a set without performance degrade. Since you match a with A, a, or aa, you can directly modify your data2 to do this right off the bat. This gives a huge performance boost. Let me show some comparison with your code and also after numpy vectorization of this function:

Your code: `22 s ± 3.53 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
As you can see, it's almost an order of magnitude of difference.

I also tried vectorizing the function, which did not improve running time much over my tweak: `2.85 s ± 231 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: This solution is a bit of a problem, I have an array(data1) like `["a", "b", "c", "aa" ]`, and the input (data 2) is `["a", "b", "c", "aa", "bb", "cc" ]`, now if I check matches based on your approach I get 4 matches. (a, b, c, aa) but instead I need the matches to be 3. Because I know "aa" is same as a.

Comment: Is there a way to overcome this and still get the speed. The Dict approach helped me with this problem.